# SFML Ambiguous conversion from derived class when implementing draw function

Tags: c++, inheritance, sfml, ambiguous

I am trying to create by own game engine where each basic is a `GameObject` which will consist of an update function and other notifiers.

Here is my code so far:

```
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "AssetManager.hpp"

class GameObject : public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable
{
public:
  virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const{
    target.draw(*this, states);
  };
};

class Sprite : public GameObject, public sf::Sprite {
public:
  Sprite(AssetManager assetManager, std::string assetName) : sf::Sprite(){
    setTexture(assetManager.getTextureNamed(assetName));
  }
};


int main(int argc, char const** argv)
{
  sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode(), "");
  AssetManager assetManager = AssetManager("/Users/iProgram/Desktop/My Game Engine/My Game Engine");
  assetManager.loadTextureWithName("tank", "tank.png", sf::Vector2f(16,16));

  Sprite tank = Sprite(assetManager, "tank");

  while(window.isOpen()){
    window.clear();
    window.draw(tank);
    window.display();
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Please note, the asset manager simply stores textures in memory and returns it when needed with a given size.

The problem is on the line: `window.draw(tank);`, I am getting the error

> Ambiguous conversion from derived class 'const Sprite' to base class 'const sf::Drawable':

Why is this as I have implemented the draw function in the `GameObject` class and how can I fix it?

Comment: `sf::Sprite` inherits from `sf::Drawable`, so `Sprite` has *two* `sf::Drawable` subobjects with separate `draw` functions.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Sprite` class inherits from `GameObject` which inherits from `sf::Drawable`. Your class also inherits from `sf::Sprite` which *also* inherits from `sf::Drawable`. Now your `Sprite` class has 2 inherited `sf::Drawable` subobjects and the compiler can't choose.

To fix this, either rethink your design or inherit virtually.

Comment: I've changed `class GameObject : public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable` to `class GameObject : public virtual sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable` and am still getting `Ambiguous conversion from derived class 'const Sprite' to base class 'const sf::Drawable':` What would I need to do?

Comment: You'd need to virtually inherit the other one too, since htat is library code that's impossible, you need to find another way

Comment: @iProgram As a suggestion, you can have a `sf::Sprite` as member of `GameObject`. This way `GameObject` can inherit from `sf::Drawable`. Inside `draw` function, you just have to draw the sprite, among any other thing.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue, I dod not have to use private inheritance as some suggested, I just needed my base class (GameObject) to inherit nothing. My Sprite class would then inherit `sf::Sprite` like so:

```
#include <SFML/Audio.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "AssetManager.hpp"

class GameObject{
public:
  virtual void update(){}
};

class Sprite : public GameObject, public sf::Sprite {
public:
  Sprite(AssetManager* assetManager, std::string assetName) : sf::Sprite(assetManager->getTextureNamed(assetName)){
  }
};

class Tank: public Sprite{
public:
  Tank(AssetManager* assetManager) : Sprite(assetManager, "tank"){
    setScale(3, 3);
  };

  virtual void update(){
    move(1,0);
  }
};

int main(int argc, char const** argv)
{
  sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode(), "");
  AssetManager* assetManager = new AssetManager("/Users/iProgram/Desktop/My Game Engine/My Game Engine");
  assetManager->loadTextureWithName("tank", "tank.png", sf::Vector2f(16,16));

  Tank tank = Tank(assetManager);
  while(window.isOpen()){
    sf::Event event;
    while(window.pollEvent(event)){
      if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed){
        window.close();
      }
    }
    tank.update();
    window.clear();
    window.draw(tank);
    window.display();
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```